# Array value won't get printed out

Tags: bash, array

I have the below bash script, but rather that I get the command executed stored in `cmd[1]` it prints `[1]: command not found`. I executed the command with the following way:

```
$ qsub -J 1-33 sicer-pbs.sh



#!/bin/bash

# Usage: qsub -J 1-33 sicer-pbs.sh

#PBS -N sicer
#PBS -l select=1:ncpus=1:mem=8G
#PBS -l walltime=30:00:00


# Generic PBS commands

source /usr/share/modules/init/bash;
module load python;

sleep $(( ($PBS_ARRAY_INDEX % 10) * 15 ));

cmd[1]="sh /usr/local/SICER_V1.1/SICER/SICER.sh /home/lorencm/bed/B1-C1-C7/ /home/lorencm/bed/B1-C1-C7/0000-C1.single.bed /home/lorencm/bed/B1-C1-C7/0006-C7.single.bed /home/lorencm/bed/B1-C1-C7/output btryoni 1 200 150 0.739196477788 600 0.01"


echo $cmd[$PBS_ARRAY_INDEX]
$cmd[$PBS_ARRAY_INDEX]
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You should use brackets when accessing elements of an array - `${cmd[...]}`. `$cmd[$PBS_ARRAY_INDEX]` is equivalent to `${cmd[0]}[$PBS_ARRAY_INDEX]`

Comment: The short answer is that you should use `eval "$cmd[$PBS_ARRAY_INDEX]"` A full answer and explanation can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668640/how-to-execute-command-stored-in-a-variable

Comment: @adonis is correct. Plus `array[ ]` does arithmetic expansion so you don't need `$`: `${cmd[PBS_ARRAY_INDEX]}` is enough. `$(( ))` also.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, great - I didn't know that! Thanks

Comment: Also, you are setting `cmd[1]`, but using `${cmd[$PBS_ARRAY_INDEX]}`.  that will only work if $PBS_ARRAY_INDEX == 1.